# How do I write a function for identifying odd positions in matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, user-defined-functions

How to create a function that generates all the elements in odd positions (e.g. 1,1 1,3 ) in a say...5-by-8 matrix?

Comment: `A(1:2:end)`? This is [fundamental matrix indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html).

Comment: Have you looked through the documentation for indexing? How have you tried solving this?

Comment: @Cris, X(1:2:inf)

Comment: Essentially, I'm want to be able to access all the elements in odd positions given any type of matrix, whether 2-by-2 or 5-by-8.

Comment: odd position as in 1,1 or 1,3 or even 5,5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by "odd" you mean where both the index for row **and** column are odd.  This means your resulting matrix should be 3 by 4.  Anyway, your code is below.

```
function Anew = yourFunc(A)
   %Create a test matrix of dimensions 5x8 of random numbers from 1-10
   A = randi(10,5,8);
   %Set the values of all elements with either index being an even number equal to zero
   for r = 1 : size(A,1)
       for c = 1 : size(A,2)
           if rem(r,2) == 0 || rem(c,2) == 0
              A(r,c) = 0;
           else
              continue
           end
       end
   end
   %Delete rows that contain ALL zeros
   for r = 1 : (size(A,1)/2) + 1
       if A(r,:) == 0
           A(r,:) = [];
       end
   end
   %Delete columns that contain ALL zeros
   for c = 1 : (size(A,2)/2) + 1
      if A(:,c) == 0
         A(:,c) = [];
      end
   end
   %State final answer
   Anew = A;
end
```

Please note that there may be a more efficient code solution, but I have never studied computer science (not my engineering discipline), so I don't know any fancy stuff.

Comment: @Joe-izy No problem! Good luck with you Project! Remember to click the up arrow and the check mark!

Comment: I just ran the code, and wow! The code is just perfect. Again, thanks @programmingEnthusiast.

Comment: @Joe-izy No problem!  Glad I could help!

Comment: I think what you are doing here can be written as `Anew=A(1:2:end,1:2:end)`.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing will stop at the greatest possible value.  So indexing x=1:2:4 will generate x = [1 3].  x=1:2:1 will generate x = 1.  So now you just need to figure out how many elements are in each matrix row and column.

**Pro-Tip**: everywhere possible in any code you write, use the length() function for indexing.  With the code below, A can be any size matrix.  This prevents needing to change your code when you change the matrix you want to analyze.

```
for row=1:2:length(A(:,1))
  for col=1:2:length(A(1,:))
    % do some operation on A(row,col)
  end
end
```

Comment: I'd rather use `size(A,1)` than `length(A(1,:))`. And within an indexing expression, `end` is the better option. I prefer to avoid `length`, actually, since it is implemented as `max(size(A))`, which is more expensive than `size(A,n)` or `numel(A)`.